# How to get total distinct count in bar chart in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I created a category bar chart. 1 asset can have multiple categories. I want to add a total where I can put the total distinct number of assets.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Analysis Menu -> Totals -> Show Column Grand Totals

Then the total will appear at the last

Comment: The problem with that is it will only total the number of items, not the distinct.